# Postgres: PANIC: WAL contains references to invalid pages

Tags: postgresql

I have a slave database that is being replicated from a Master DB.

All of a sudden, my slave DB just exited and wasn't able to restart. Here are the error messages when it exits. Similar ones appear when I restart:

```
WARNING:  page 21561636 of relation base/16384/54391 is uninitialized
CONTEXT:  xlog redo visible: rel 1663/16384/54391; blk 21561636
PANIC:  WAL contains references to invalid pages
CONTEXT:  xlog redo visible: rel 1663/16384/54391; blk 21561636
LOG:  startup process (PID 1573) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

Both slave and master are using **Postgres 9.2.3** in a **Centos 5** quad-core server with 32 GB of RAM each.

When I try to restart the slave, with "zero_damaged_pages=true", the server still refuses to start with lines like the ones above.

At this point, I don't care if the slave ever starts as I can start from scratch. But is this an issue with Postgres? Has anyone encountered this and is it fixed in future versions?

Looking up research online doesn't give me much confidence, so that's why I'm posting here.

Comment: You might want to also try posting this question to the Postgresql mailing lists, where most of the core developers regularly answer questions. I suggest the pgsql-general list. See http://www.postgresql.org/list/ for directions on how to sign up (if you haven't already).

Comment: Or for a (potentially) more immediate response, you could try the folks in the #postgresql IRC channel: http://www.postgresql.org/community/irc/

Comment: I see Andres Freund has delivered an answer http://markmail.org/message/3hurskbx7hwqdapw . FWIW, it appears to be related to an earlier thread that mentions the commit where the bug was patched: http://markmail.org/message/3feyoaq5alijqkjs

Comment: I just experienced this in 9.2.6 on ubuntu 12.04.4 - is there a known solution for this besides "restart the replica"?

Comment: @Geesu A question first: Is your slave database in the same network as the master? Same data center?

Comment: No but I had 3 slaves coming off of one master.  The first was only 5 hops away (but 70 ping), the other 2 within 10 hops and 50ms away

Comment: I heard somewhere that you run into these issues more often if the slave is not in same datacenter as master. That's what happened to me previously. I moved slave to same DC as master now, and after a month, havent had any issues but its too soon to say.